# how do i deal with missing string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to insert data into my table but when I press "enter" nothing happens and the next sentence starts with '>.
I know it means missing string but I don't see it
this is my code

```
INSERT 
INTO events
VALUES
('13', '2021.03.13', 
'vet', 
'Dehidration. Spider's body loses more fluids than it does take in. If spider is not threated, it can get worse and become a serious problem.',
'10',
'5');
```

then it shows "'>"
how to deal with this?

Comment: instead of pressing enter, try using the character `\n`

Comment: Where do you press 'enter' ? Please add more details!\

Comment: add slash and quote `.....Spider\'s body....`

Answer (score 1):

The fourth value that you are entering contains a ' which is closing the string early, try this;

INSERT
INTO events
VALUES
('13', '2021.03.13',
'vet',
'Dehydration. Spider\'s body loses more fluids than it does take in. If spider is not threated, it can get worse and become a serious problem.',
'10',
'5');

In this case the \ lets the database know that you want to store the character ', instead of ending the string early.

Answer (score 0):

> Please use this mysqli_real_escape_string(db_connection, $your_string)

OR

you may write single quote like this => `\'`